# Read a list from a Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: 1]

Well, how can I work with these long codes that look as if they are encrypted? How do I read the data from this list?

I have tried making several loops which turned out to be a bad idea.

Comment: Here's one approach for dealing with those dynamic keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72614555/how-can-i-get-data-from-various-nodes-in-a-realtime-database-in-flutter/72616897#72616897. It that doesn't help you solve your problem, please edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you are working in kotlin or java?

Comment: @SohaibAhmed JS